# Service Bus Migration .Net Framework to .Net Standard 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, amqp, azureservicebus, .net-standard

3 years ago, I worked on a corebanking project where we used Service Bus and it worked very well, and now we are trying to make a migration From .Net Framework to .Net Standard 2.0 but we still do not have an accurate view on the feasibility of things, I would just like to know if the current version of Service Bus is supported by .Net Standard 2.0 .

Thank you in advance. of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would just like to know if the current version of Service Bus is supported by .Net Standard 2.0

The question probably should be inverted - what version of .NET Standard the new Azure Service Bus client is compliant with. As of today, it's compliant with .NET Standard 1.3. This means you won't have the features that are associated with .NET Standard 2.0. One of those would be [transaction semantics](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/milestone/9).

[Future milestones](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/milestones) contain issues for features that are not available yet. You can track specific ones on GitHub if you happened to rely on those.

Note that there were some design changes in the [new client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.azure.servicebus) such as

- [Entity clients vs message senders/receivers](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus/tree/master/samples/DotNet/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus).
- Simplified [brokered message](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/Message.cs), removal of message serialization.
- [Separation of run-time and configuration planes](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues/65).
- Addition on incoming and going pipelines to support [plugins](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet-plugins).
- etc.

You should analyze those and review how they will affect your migration. The [repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet) is now open-sourced and it is much easier to follow up with the development team to [raise issues](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues).